# SQL query to its equivalent JSON string in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, json

i want to convert SQL query to its equivalent JSON string.
for eg in php:-

```
    `Query :` SELECT user_id,user_name FROM dummy_data_users WHERE user_status='1'
`Code :` sql2json("SELECT user_id,user_name FROM dummy_data_users WHERE user_status='1'");
```

JSON :

```
[
    {"user_id":"1","user_name":"Binny"},
    {"user_id":"2","user_name":"Bill Gates"},
    {"user_id":"3","user_name":"George Bush"},
    {"user_id":"4","user_name":"Secret Agent"}
]
```

I want to do the same using JavaScript, but http://jslinq.codeplex.com/ is not suitable for me any other option ?

Comment: Do you mean SQL or mysql?

Comment: SQL commands in jasper